# AIR for iOS App not showing on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, flash, air, flash-cs6

I have published an ipa from Flash CS6 without any errors (i.e., certificates and provisioning profiles seem to be in order) and ticked the "Install application on the connected iOS device" on the deployment tab.

All goes to plan and even a "IPA file has been installed on the connected iOS device successfully." is displayed.

However, the app is not showing on the connected iPad. And manually installing it through iTunes doesnt solve it (still not showing). The mobile provisioning profile is present on the iPad, but not the app itself.

Am I missing something really obvious?

I'm using Flash CS6, with AIR 3.4 for iOS and publishing to an iPad 2 with iOS 6 installed. iTunes 11 is also installed on my machine.

Would really appreciate help on this?

Comment: are you sure it was not added to a group somehow. I had a similar issue then realized i used same certificate for another app which was placed in a group after install. Also can you use the iOS search function to check for the app name ?

Answer (score 0):

if the ipad refuse to install the app it's because you don't sign the app with the good certificate.

you may check this tut
http://devgirl.org/2011/06/20/flexair-for-ios-development-process-explained/

Additional tips :
itunes is ok but iFunBox is easier and faster
http://www.i-funbox.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've installed it via iFunBox and it worked perfectly!!

Comment: What's weird is it wont install via either Flash CS6 or iTunes (11). Not sure what's going on, but at least I've got some route to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your APP_ID while publishing the IPA file from flash CS6, if it is not as per your certificate and provisioning file, then it might cause the problem.

Try to look at this.